# Constraint vs Parameter - way to force collection as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I am wondering if there is any difference between these two methods. Second one look more natural, but that shouldn't be the only reason to use it. Maybe there are some performance issues or some diabolic mambojambo related to any of them?

```
void FirstMethod<T>(T a) where T : IEnumerable<Animal>
{
    ...
}

void SecondMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> a) where T : Animal
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's going to depend on what you do with the parameter.  The two aren't identical, but the differences may or may not be germane to a particular implementation.  The two are functionally different, so performance wouldn't be the primary concern, it's what they would actually do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that you can easily pass `IEnumerable<Dog>` to the second method,
but when you pass it to the first method it'll just be implicitly converted to an `IEnumerable<Animal>`

Take a look at the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kcvDCs)

**Edited** Thanks @Servy for comment.

Comment: You can pass an `IEnumerable<Dog>` to the first too, it'll just be implicitly converted to an `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is declared as `out` (covariant). It can take a `IEnumerable<Dog>`.

Comment: It's defined as `IEnumerable<out T>`, which means it's covariant. You can cast `IEnumerable<Dog>` to `IEnumerable<Animal>`

Comment: You've stated that they accept different types.  That is obvious enough from the signature.  That's still not saying anything meaningful about the differences.

Comment: So, is there any real difference between them since collections' interfaces are variant?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this sample in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{   
    var cats = new [] { new Cat() };
    FirstMethod(cats);
    SecondMethod(cats);
}
interface Animal
{
}
class Cat : Animal
{
}
void FirstMethod<T>(T a) where T : IEnumerable<Animal>
{
    var b = a.FirstOrDefault();
}
void SecondMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> a) where T : Animal
{
    var b = a.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

By looking at the IL code generated, there is no difference between the 2 call to methods and they both accept `cats` as parameter.

Edit: the differences occur IN the methods as seen below. (thank you @servy for the remark)

```
IL_001D:  ldarg.0     
IL_001E:  ldloc.0     // cats
IL_001F:  call        UserQuery.FirstMethod
IL_0024:  nop         
IL_0025:  ldarg.0     
IL_0026:  ldloc.0     // cats
IL_0027:  call        UserQuery.SecondMethod

FirstMethod:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  box         02 00 00 1B 
IL_0007:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault
IL_000C:  stloc.0     // b
IL_000D:  ret         

SecondMethod:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  call        05 00 00 2B 
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // b
IL_0008:  ret
```

Using a decompiler on this IL code shows where the boxing occurs to ensure type safety.

```
private void Main()
{
    Cat[] a = new Cat[1]
    {
        new Cat()
    };
    this.FirstMethod<Cat[]>(a);
    this.SecondMethod<Cat>((IEnumerable<Cat>) a);
}

private void FirstMethod<T>(T a) where T : IEnumerable<Animal>
{
    Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<Animal>((IEnumerable<Animal>) a);
}

private void SecondMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> a) where T : Animal
{
    Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<T>(a);
}
```

Comment: Both compile.  The are not identical (other than that both methods do nothing).

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure to understand why you say they are not identical. I've added IL Code to illustrate. Both methods are identical both in calling and executing (a is a IEnumerable<Animal>)

Comment: They accept different types, have different behaviors, can do different things with the parameter that they accept, etc.  That they both compile doesn't mean they're identical.  The only reason they're identical in your example is that neither has any implementation.  If they had implementations they are all sorts of ways they can differ.

Comment: In fact, parameter `a` ends implementing `IEnumerable<Animal>` in both cases. I agree that each of these methods can do different things as they have different signatures, but there is no reason to choose the one over the other based on performance or other diabolic reasons as they end producing the same IL code.

Comment: No, the parameter will not end up being of the same type.  In your own code the second method accepts an `IEnumerable<Cat>` not an `IEnumerable<Animal>`.  And if you type `cats` as an `Animal[]` then the first method would actually be of that type, while the second method would be an `IEnumerable<Animal>`.  Those differences aren't germane to a method that does nothing.  They could be germane to another implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I see what you mean now :). I've updated my sample and conclusion.

Comment: You've now stated that they are not identical, rather than incorrectly stating that they were identical.  You've still said nothing about what the differences are or how they matter.